# Add a class if div contains specific first and second letter with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, substring, contains, addclass

I want to know how I have to combine the snippets I have made... I want to check a div on the first two letters... If they contain a particular combination like `Ab`, than I want to give it a `class` (or an `ID`)....

How can I do this?

I have made this so far:

```
$('#test:contains("Ab")').substr(0, 2).parent().addClass("NewClass");
```

The HTML:

```
<li id="blabla">
    <a id="test">Abnormal</a>
</li>
```

The CSS:

```
.NewClass { background: black;  }
a {   color: blue;   }
```

The problem is, I guess, that I don't put the substring on the right place. But then again: where is the right place?

PS: here is the fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Y6UVX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this:

```
var texto = $('#test').html();
var comp = texto.substring(0,2);

if (comp == 'Ab')
{
  $('#test').addClass('NewClass');
}
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6UVX/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()`

```
$("li a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().substr(0,2).toUpperCase() == "AB";
}).addClass("NewClass");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6UVX/2/

Comment: Oeh, that one I didn't know. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery `.filter()`:

```
$containing = $('#blabla > a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().substring(0,2) == "Ab";
});

if ($containing.length > 0) {
    $containing.first().parent().addClass('NewClass');
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TKA3D/1/)

Comment: Thanks man. I can't accept all and I can't give you an upvote because of my low points. If I get higher here, you'll get it! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! But I think tymeJV's answer is more generic than mine so he deserves the points.